# For some reason after inputting cin text, the cout comes out blank. Any ideas?

Tags: c++, if-statement, int, cout, cin

So I am trying to create a simple Text RPG. But, this one problem is holding me back.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int input;
    long Sven;
    long Macy;

    cout<<"Choose your Character- 1.Sven or 2.Macy: ";
    cin>>input;
    cin.ignore();

    if ( input == Sven ){
        cout<<"Welcome to CRPG, my good Sir!";
    }

    if ( input == Macy ){
        cout<<"Girls cant fight, go back: ";
    }
}
```

So this code here is what I have at the moment. When I run the program, it allows me to type the name of the character I want to choose. But, the output is always just a blank area of text. I am more or less new to C++ but, I have nice prior knowledge. Any help is great.

Comment: `Sven` and `Macy` were not assigned values. They could contain anything. Assign them values like `long Sven = 1;` and `long Macy = 2;` when you declare them

Comment: Oh kk, I will try that. Thanks. EDIT: It didn't work out. I even tried `if ( input == 1 )` with `long Sven = 1;`. Still blank.

Comment: Move `cin.ignore()` to the very end of the program. And what string are you typing? You should be typing `1` or `2`. If you're typing `Sven` or `Macy` into the console, use a `std::string` and compare with `"Sven"` and `"Macy"`.

Comment: Just flush `cout` to see the actual output: put `cout << endl;` at the very end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What threw me off is when you said **it allows me to type the name of the character I want to choose**

In that case, go ahead with comparing the strings:

EDIT: As Mohammed suggested, comparing strings can be done directly:

```
string input;

cout<<"Choose your Character- 1.Sven or 2.Macy: ";
cin>>input;
cin.ignore();

if ( input == "Sven" ){
    cout<<"Welcome to CRPG, my good Sir!";
}

else if ( input == "Macy"){
    cout<<"Girls cant fight, go back: ";
}
```

Comment: Why `strcmp` when you're using `std::string`?

Comment: true, I meant C String. You can use == or std::string::compare in this case.

Comment: Throw in an `else` and you have mine :p

Comment: Haha yeah that's a good point. I just didn't want to change the code a lot from the OP. Although thanks for pointing out, will do.